# Copy value of img to clipboard (and paste it?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to have a functionality similar to messenger apps like whatsapp on my website, where you can click on a smiley- `<img>` and the value of this `<img>` should then be stored in the clipboard and maybe even copied to an `<input>` field.

Help would be very much appreciated, I don't really know how to get this done. Javascript or jQuery, both is fine.
Just the start:

```
<img src="..." id="smiley" value=":)" style="cursor:pointer">
   <input type="text" id="copyhere">

jQuery('#smiley').on('click', function () {

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Document.execCommand()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) with *copy* as parameter.

```js
$('#smiley').on('click', function() {
  var value = $(this).attr('value');

  copyToClipboard(value);
  
  $('#copyhere').val(value);
});

function copyToClipboard(value) {
  var $tmpInput = $('<input>');
  $tmpInput.val(value);
  $('body').append($tmpInput);
  $tmpInput.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  $tmpInput.remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="..." id="smiley" value=":)" style="cursor:pointer">
<input type="text" id="copyhere">
```

Comment: Thank you, when running the code here, it does exactly what I need. I tried to copy it to my joomla site in a module position and the same exact code does't work. I just replaced the $ with jQuery because that often causes trouble in joomla. Do you have an idea why this would't work? It's not in the "main content area" but in a side module.

Comment: Turns out the jQuery version on my site was too old for this. Added the include and it works. thanks a lot!